# Hessian Spring configuration

Tags: hessian

This question may seem basic, but I've been struggling with it, I will really appreciate your help. How do I configure hessain to use DAO the serviceDao returns null. below is my snippet code. 
.......

```
 <bean id="securityService" class="com.polaris.service.SecurityServiceImpl">
    <!-- any additional properties, maybe a DAO? -->
    <property name="serviceDao" ref="securityDAO"/>
</bean>

<bean name="/securityService.http" class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianServiceExporter">
    <property name="service" ref="securityService"/>        
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.polaris.service.SecurityService"/>

</bean>
```